# Can I use geofence to mark all roads within the shape coords as avoids or favors?

Tags: here-maps-rest, heremaps

Fleet telematics API tool https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api has examples "Prefer certain links and route through them" and "Avoid certain links and route by avoiding them".

The question is does HERE maps provide an API to mark geofence as avoid or favor similarly how it provides the ability to mark route links as avoids or favors?

UPD: Additionally is there a way of matching router links within the geofence so that we can get them and mark as avoids/favors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geofence/shape can be used only to restrict the area. See **Overlay Override Area** chapter in [Fleet telematics Custom Routes docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html).
So you can't do areas "preferred". Only route links — roads can be marked both either "favored" or "avoided".